# Why is the genus (in terms of Euler characteristic) the maximum number of disj. closed curves that can be embedded in a surface without separating it?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

Let $S$ be a compact surface and $g$ its genus defined in terms of Euler characteristic.
Why is $g$ the maximum number of disjoint simple closed curves that can be embedded in the surface without disconnecting it?
I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to prove it or give me a reference. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what kind of simple closed curves are allowed here, since I can cut out any number of small circles from any compact surface without disconnecting it.

Comment: @Ted If I understand you correctly, your small circles do disconnect the surface: you're separating the part of the surface inside the small circle from the part outside of it. In contrast, scc's that go "through the holes" of the surface do not disconnect.

Comment: For an orientable $S$, each embedded circle will have a trivial tubular neighborhood; if this curve does not disconnect the surface, removing this neighborhood and capping the two boundary components with disks will increase the Euler characteristic by 2 (as you can check). Thus after doing this $g$ times you get a sphere, where every embedded circle disconnects.

Comment: @SamFreedman I'm sorry, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the orientable case, consider a closed, connected, oriented surface $S$ of genus $g$. The genus is related to its Euler characterstic $\chi(S)$ by the formula $\chi(S)=2-2g$, and this number $g = 1 - \frac{\chi(S)}{2}$ is equal to that maximal number of pairwise disjoint circles in $S$ that do not separate $S$. Here's the proof.

When you cut along a circle, the Euler characteristic does not change. So if you cut $S$ along $k$ circles, and assuming those circles do not disconnect $S$, you will get a compact, connected, orientable surface-with-boundary that I'll denote $A_k$, that has $2k$ boundary circles, and that has Euler characterstic
$$\chi(A_k) = \chi(S)
$$
You can then glue a single disc to each of those $2k$ circles, to get a closed connected surface that I'll denote $B_k$. The same logic (gluing along circles does not change the Euler characteristic), together with the fact that each individual disc has Euler characterstic $1$, gives the result
$$\chi(B_k) = \chi(A_k) + 2k = \chi(S) + 2k
$$
It is known that the maximum Euler characteristic of a connected, closed, orientable surface is the Euler characteristic of the sphere which is equal to $2$, and therefore
$$\chi(S) + 2k \le 2
$$
Substituting $\chi(S)=2-2g$ one obtains $g \le k$.

To show that the maximum $k=g$ is obtained, start with a sphere whose Euler characteristic equals $2$, remove $2g$ discs which reduces the Euler characterstic to $2-2g$, and now glue those circles in pairs to give a closed oriented surface of the same Euler characterstic $2-2g$ as your surface $S$, together with a system of $g$ circles that do not separate the surface. Since the Euler characteristic is a complete topological invariant of closed, connected, oriented surfaces, and knowing that $\chi(S)=2-2g$, this surface is homeomorphic to the original surface $S$.

---

Now for the non-orientable case. Let $S$ be a closed, connected, nonorientable surface. The terminology here is less standard, so I'll be careful and refer to the *nonorientable genus* $g$ of $S$, which is related to Euler characterstic by the formula $\chi(S)=2-g$, and is again equal to the maximal number of pairwise disjoint circles in $S$ that do not separate $S$.

The proof is a bit trickier in the nonorientable case, due to the fact that there are two kinds of circles in $S$: two-sided and one-sided (in an orientable surface, every circle is two-sided). So, suppose that we have a pairwise disjoint collection of $k$ circles in $S$ that do not separate $S$. We may partition this collection into $k_1$ one-sided circles and $k_2$ two-sided circles, with $k = k_1 + k_2$. Again let $A$ be the connected surface-with-boundary obtained by cutting along these circles. Again $\chi(A)=\chi(S)$. But in this case the number of boundary circles of $A$ is equal to $k_1 + 2 k_2$. So, gluing in discs produces a closed surface $B$ with $\chi(B)=\chi(A)+k_1 + 2k_2 = \chi(S) + k_1 + 2 k_2$. We therefore have
$$2 - g + k = \chi(S) + k_1 + k_2 \le \chi(S) + k_1 + 2 k_2 = \chi(B) \le 2
$$
and so
$$k \le g
$$
To show that the maximum is achieved, one can get a hint by examining the above chain of inequalities. First, if $k_2 \ge 1$ then we get strict inequality $k < g$. Also, if $B$ is not the sphere then we again get strict inequality $k < g$. So, the only way that the maximum can be achieved is by a collection of $g$ one-sided circles which, when cut along, give a sphere with $g$ discs removed.

So, start from a sphere with $g$ discs removed, having $g$ boundary circles. Identify each boundary circle to itself by the antipodal map. The result is a non-orientable surface of Euler characteristic $2-g$. Since closed, connected, non-orientable surfaces are classified by their Euler characterstic, the resulting surface is homeomorphic to your original surface.

---

Here's one last comment relating the two concepts of genus. Given a closed, connected, orientable surface $S$, its genus is also equal to the number of toruses ($T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$) needed so that their connected sum is homeomorphic to $S$. And given a closed, connected, nonorientable surface $S$, its nonorientable genus equals the number of projective planes needed so that their connected sum is homeomorphic to $S$. Often these are the descriptions used to define genus and nonorientable genus.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. The Euler characteristic of the disk is one.

Comment: Oops, of course.

Comment: I was wandering if there would be an analogous argument if $S$ in non orientable. In this case, if we cut along one circle the new surface will have one boundary component? I am a little confused with this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the "nonorientable" tag. I'll have to think about this. But, one thing about circles on a nonorientable surface is that there are two kinds: one-sided (with Möbius band neighborhood) and two-sided (with annulus neighborhood).

Comment: See if it makes sense. When removing $k$ circles from from a non orientable surface $S$, firstly we remove a one sided circle to obtain a orientable surface with one boundary component (wild guess). Then remove $k-1$ more circles to get the inequality $2k$$\leq$$g$. Then try to finish the argument as you did. Does it make sense?

Comment: I added a description of the nonorientable case. It turns out rather differently than in your last comment.

Comment: Given a surface $S$, there may be many distinct homeomorphism types of the complement $S-c$ when $c \subset S$ is a simple closed curve. For example, if $S$ is a closed surface of genus $2$ then I count 3 different homeomorphism types: a two-holed torus; a pair of one-holed toruses; and a one-holed genus two surface plus a disc. Similarly, if $S$ is nonorientable and $c$ is restricted to one-sided curves, there may be many different homeomorphism types of the complement $S-c$.

Comment: Yes, there does exist a set of $g$ orientation reversing simple closed curves which are pairwise disjoint. But as you have observed with the connected sum of the torus and projective plane, it is *not true* that for every orientation reversing simple closed curve $c$ there exists a set of $g$ orientation reversing simple closed curves $C$ which are pairwise disjoint, such that $c$ is in $C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned a lot from you

Comment: That's great, glad to help.

Comment: Keep in mind also that when your post gets good answers, you should pick one of those answers and accept it by clicking on the check box. That gives reputation points to answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE. I want to assume some familiarity about [pants decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)#Pants_decompositions) (see the references linked here). For simplicity, I'll assume that $S$ is orientable without boundary, but I think you can modify the argument to adapt to boundary components.

---

A pants decomposition for a connected genus $g$ surface $S$ consists of $2g - 2$ pairs of pants. We'll need to glue at least $(2g - 2) - 1 = 2g - 3$ of these pairs of pants together in order to form a connected surface.

At the outset, there are $3(2g - 2) = 6g - 6$ boundary cuffs which are all pairwise-glued to form $S$. In other words, we performed $(6g-6)/2 = 3g - 3$ gluings total. But we were forced to do at least $(2g - 3)$ of them, meaning that we did
$$(3g - 3) - (2g - 3) = g$$
gluings "just for fun." In other words, there were $g$ gluings that we didn't have to make in order to keep $S$ connected. These curves are the maximal set of disjoint scc's in this alternate characterization of genus.